# SQS SendMessageBatch Concurrency Limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

What is the maximum concurrency limit on SQS FIFO Queue? If I call 200 sendMessageBatch APIs with 10 messages(< 256KB) per API invocation. Will SQS be able to handle this?

Sample Code:

```
   const totalSqsBatches = 200;
   const sqsPromises = [];

   for (let batch = 0; batch < totalSqsBatches; batch++) {
     sqsPromises.push(
       sqs.sendMessageBatch({
         Entries: sqsEntries.slice(batch, (batch + 1) * 10),
         QueueUrl: URL,
       })
     );
   }

  await Promise.all(sqsPromises).catch(err => console.error(err)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will.

> If you use batching, FIFO queues support up to 3,000 messages per second, per API method (SendMessageBatch, ReceiveMessage, or DeleteMessageBatch). **The 3000 messages per second represent 300 API calls, each with a batch of 10 messages.**

This means you can invoke 200 times `sendMessageBatch` API. Also, 300 API calls is a soft limit and can be increased by contacting AWS support.

Besides that, there is [High throughput for FIFO queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/high-throughput-fifo.html). You can go up to 3,000 API calls, each with a batch of 10 messages.

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-messages.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Alex for the useful information.